# How to encourage/create effective tagging protocol

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I have seen a few questions where people want to do something like convert a file, or they ask a question about a specific programming tool. Then they don't tag the post with the programming language they are using, and or don't tag with the file formats they want to convert between.

How can we as a community moving forward encourage proper tagging? Should we make a one tag minimum, to remind people to use tags?

Possibly allow more than 5 tags. In bioinformatics it would be easy to use more than 5 tags every post. Possibly we could have 0-2 coding-language tags then have the other standard 5 tags.

Comment: Prompting to add tags and auto-suggesting tags based on text mining of the thread are some of the ideas worth considering. Not just for this SE, but for the entire Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

We can't change the number of allowed tags, that's part of the system. I mean, maybe we could ask Stack Exchange, but they're not very good with that sort of thing. Nor do I really think it's needed, really, 5 tags is plenty and, as you point out, many people don't even use that.

I think the best thing we can do is to simply edit the questions and add the relevant tags. The beauty of the Stack Exchange model is that it is collaborative and everyone can edit or suggest edits. So whenever you see something that can be fixed, just fix it!

Comment: I definitely agree with everything you said. I wish they had a better  mechanism like auto suggested tags option. Maybe forcing you to at least click in tag section and prompt before submitting are you sure you don't want to add in any tags. We'll just have to keep editing till all the questions and answers are fixed!